# Парсинг HTML в массив

Tags: jquery, парсер

Есть HTML в виде:

```
<b>Element1</b> text1<br>
<b>Element2</b> text2<br>
```

Как извлечь в массив все Element со значением Text с помощью JQuery?

```
[{Element1: 'text1'}, {Element2: 'text2'}]
```

Comment: `{Element1: 'text1', Element2: 'text2'}` --- это не массив

Comment: сорри, конечно так:
[{Element1: 'text1'}, {Element2: 'text2'}]

Answer (score 1):

```js
let result = 
  toParse.innerHTML.trim().split('<br>')
    .map(row=>/^<b>([^<]+)<\/b>\s*(.*)$/.exec(row.trim()))
    .filter(arr=>arr)
    .map(arr=>Object.fromEntries([arr.splice(1,2)]));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<div id="toParse">
<b>Element1</b> text1<br>
<b>Element2</b> text2<br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Использование jQuery для данной задачи неоправданно, но раз так указано в метках вопроса, то будет так:

```js
let arr = [];
$('b').each(function() {
  arr.push({[this.textContent]: this.nextSibling.textContent.trim()});
});

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<b>Element1</b> text1<br>
<b>Element2</b> text2<br>
```